# Aria Templates - Warning of "expression is null or undefined" in debug mode for a template file

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications, ariatemplates

I'm working in debug mode with AT and I'm continuously getting a warning of the kind:

```
[aria.templates.TemplateCtxt] Template guides.todo_mio.view.Todo 
Line 44: expression is null or undefined.
```

Line 44 in my Todo.tpl is:

```
${( function() { console.log("passed"); } )()}
```

that I use to log what's happening into the template. And it works btw..

Do you have any suggestion?

Thanks.

Comment: is `${...}` an aria template syntax?

Comment: yes. it's a way to embed JS code inside the html file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Aria Templates, whatever is done inside a TPL file should produce some output.

The warning is to notify you that there might be an issue in your code, because

- you're calling a function that doesn't return (maybe you forgot to return)
- you're using undefined variables
- you're calling methods that are not used for producing markup

The latter is more a design issue, methods that are not related to the view should be called in other places (`$dataReady`/`$afterRefresh` and so on)

If you're fine with methods returning undefined you can either

- modify your method to return an empty string
- use `eat` or `empty` [template modifier](http://ariatemplates.com/usermanual/latest/writing_templates#modifiers)

  ```
  ${( function() { console.log("passed"); } )()|eat}
  ```